# How do I read from a yml file in a controller in symfony2?

Tags: php, symfony-2.8

I have a random `name.yml` file inside lets say my `src/AppBundle/Controller` folder. The content inside the YML file is simple:

```
name: utkarsh
```

I need to access this from my controller, and have tried to fetch them with

```
$name = $this->getName('name');
```

from within my controller file. When I try this, I get this error message:

```
Attempted to call an undefined method named "getName" of class "AppBundle\Controller\DefaultController".
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's just going to be a general file, and wouldn't better be part of the framework's configuration (for example, in the parameters.yml file), you can parse/read the file using the [Yaml component](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/yaml.html#reading-yaml-files), which is already used by the Symfony framework.

```
use Symfony\Component\Yaml\Yaml;

$values = Yaml::parse(file_get_contents('/path/to/name.yml'));
echo $values['name'];
```

If the file you are loading is in the same directory as the code that is running it, you can use the PHP Automagic constants - `__DIR__`, `file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/name.yml')`, or use it as a relative base to work from.

Comment: I used `$values = Yaml::parse(file_get_contents('/src/AppBundle/Controller/Name.yml'));`. But it says `Warning: file_get_contents(./src/AppBundle/Controller/Name.yml): failed to open stream: No such file or directory`

Comment: ok got it. had to use the full path /var/www/html/TestProject/src/AppBundle/Controller/Name.yml

Answer (score 2):

Don't just put your YML file in the Controllers folder. Instead, move your YML file into your bundles' config directory. See below,

```
AppBundle\Resource\config\abc.yml
```

Then, import this file in your services.yml file. See below,

```
imports:
    - { resource: abc.yml }
```

And, make sure you abc.yml file will have a structure like this,

```
parameters:
  name: utkarsh
```

Finally, you can access this parameter inside the Controller by calling like this,

```
$this->container->getParameter('name');
```

I hope this helps :)

Cheers!

Comment: I tried your solution . It says `The parameter "name" must be defined.
`

Comment: Hello, @utkarsh2k2, please check your YML file. It has to have the same structure as any other YML files. Did you put the "name" under "parameters" heading?

Comment: That's really strange. It should work. Did you have the correct import line in your services.yml file? Make sure both services.yml and name.yml files are in the same directory :)